# find layout type of a view

Tags: android, layout, view, expandablelistadapter

I have a custom ExpandableListAdapter where I specified the getGroup(...) as following:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //do stuff
    if(something) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.tasks_list_group_with_child, null);
        }

        TextView taskNameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tlgwc_task_name);
        //do stuff


    } else {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.tasks_list_group_without_child, null);        
        }

        TextView taskNameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tlgwoc_task_name);
        //do stuff

    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Now the problem is when I change the data that I use in the Adapter, it's possible that the parameter (view object which is reused) 'convertView' of the getGroup(...) method hasn't the correct layout anymore. How do I check if its a View with the R.layout.tasks_list_group_without_child or the R.layout.tasks_list_group_with_child layout?

As the API says "convertView: the old view to reuse, if possible. You should check that this view is non-null and of an appropriate type before using", but how?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the BaseExpandableListAdapter you can use view types, so in your case the group have to:
- override getGroupTypeCount to return 2 or more ([1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html#getGroupTypeCount%28%29))
- override getGroupType to return a different number for each different layout you need ([2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html#getGroupType%28int%29))
- then when inflating the view you call getGroupType to know the kind of the view and if convertView is not null, the view on it will be the view from the type you want, because android uses this to keep track of the different kinds of view you defined and recycles the same type of view you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a tag to the view

`view.setTag( "TAG" );`

and retrieve it from the convertView.

Read more about it: [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Tags)

Answer (score 0):

The 'correct' way to do this is using the getGroupTypeCount technique, mentioned by nininho. If you want a quick and dirty way to do this though, the same effect can be achieved by having a single layout for R.layout.tasks_list_group_with_child and R.layout.tasks_list_group_without_child but make some elements gone in one case and visible in the other.